# Join two tables in BigQuery, using key-value pairs on one table to create columns in the merged table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery, but I'm struggling to correctly join the content of one into the other.

The first table is of the form (DataUsers):

| userID | name | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| us1 | John | Anders |
| us2 | Terry | Garcia |

And the second looks like this (DataInfo):

| userID | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| us1 | address1 | us1FirstHome |
| us2 | address1 | us2FirstHome |
| us1 | address2 | us1SecondHome |
| us2 | address2 | us2SecondHome |
| us1 | address3 | us1ThirdHome |
| us2 | address3 | us2ThirdHome |

Since there's a key-value relationship, I would like to create a column for each one of the keys.

I have tried with a query like the next to join the tables:

```
SELECT
  i.name,
  i.lastname,
  CASE WHEN u.key = 'address1' THEN u.value END AS address1 ,
  CASE WHEN u.key = 'address2' THEN u.value END AS address2 ,
  CASE WHEN u.key = 'address3' THEN u.value END AS address3 ,
FROM
  `DataInfo` i
INNER JOIN
  `DataUsers` u
ON
  i.userID = u.userID
WHERE
  (u.key="address1"
    OR u.key="address2"
    OR u.key="address3")
```

However, the result is a table like this:

| userID | name | lastname | address1 | address2 | address3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| us1 | John | Anders | us1FirstHome | null | null |
| us1 | John | Anders | null | us1SecondHome | null |
| us1 | John | Anders | null | null | us1ThirdHome |
| us2 | Terry | Garcia | us2FirstHome | null | null |
| us2 | Terry | Garcia | null | us2SecondHome | null |
| us2 | Terry | Garcia | null | null | us2ThirdHome |

Instead of the expected table which would look like this:

| userID | name | lastname | address1 | address2 | address3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| us1 | John | Anders | us1FirstHome | us1SecondHome | us1ThirdHome |
| us2 | Terry | Garcia | us2FirstHome | us2SecondHome | us2ThirdHome |

- What would be the correct way to join the tables, and not getting the null values in BigQuery?
- Is there a way to automatically create the columns according the keys, so that it is not necessary to hardcode their names?

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below (least verbose) approach

```
select * from (
  select * from DataUsers 
  left join DataInfo using(UserID)
)
pivot (min(value) for key in ('address1', 'address2', 'address3'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked almost perfectly! However, now I'm getting repeated columns like 'address1_1', 'address2_1', with similar values to the columns 'address1', 'address2'.

Do you know how that might be solved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT i.name, i.lastname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN u.key = 'address1' THEN u.value END) AS address1 ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN u.key = 'address2' THEN u.value END) AS address2 ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN u.key = 'address3' THEN u.value END) AS address3 ,
FROM `DataInfo` i INNER JOIN
     `DataUsers` u
     ON i.userID = u.userID
WHERE u.key IN ('address1', 'address2', 'address3')
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked quite well, but I'm accepting Mikhail's answer for being least verbose, although both options worked as expected